# Unsafe Node.js code, though in a trusted environment

Tags: javascript, security, node.js

I am going to run a private Node.js app in a local network which will take user code submissions and evaluate them. Since it is a trusted environment (just friends), I have not bothered at all about any kind of security. I am new to Node.js and this is only my third app.

I am seeking review of the function that actually processes the submitted code. Some things I'd like to know some feedback on:

- Is this the right way to implement the functionality?
- Am I following Node.js/JS best practices in my code?
- I am not sure if my identifiers are named alright according to convention. I come from an iOS background and I'm used to long descriptive names.
- The functions scoped within the route handler are bothering me somehow, but I don't know of a better way to do it.

Some background:

- Using passport.js with mongoose to manage the 15-20 users.
- Errors are not really accounted for, the ones who are going to use it can fix them themselves.

The code:

```
router.post('/', function(req, res) {
    if (!req.body.problem || !req.body.lang || !req.body.code) {
        res.render('index', { message: 'Missing information.' });
        return;
    }

    var wd = path.join(__dirname, '../sandbox/' + req.user.username + '/' + req.body.problem);
    var sourcename = req.body.problem + '.' + req.body.lang;

    function finishedWithSuccess(success) {
        var newScore = req.user.codeScore + parseInt(req.body.bet) * (success ? 1 : -1);
        var message = success ? ('Good job! +' + req.body.bet.toString() + '!') : ('Incorrect solution. -' + req.body.bet.toString() + '.');

        Account.update({ username: req.user.username }, { $set: { codeScore: newScore }}, function(error, user) {
            if (error) {
                console.log('error saving: ' + error);
                res.render('index', { message: 'Error updating database. Contact event master.' });
            }
            else res.render('index', { message: message, success: success });
        });
    }
    function finishedWithError(runtime) {
        var newScore = req.user.codeScore - parseInt(req.body.bet) / 2;
        var message = (runtime ? 'Runtime' : 'Compilation') + ' error. You lose half your bet. Attached are some files for your debugging pleasure.';

        Account.update({ username: req.user.username }, { $set: { codeScore: newScore }}, function(error, user) {
            if (error) {
                console.log('error saving: ' + error);
                res.render('index', { message: 'Error updating database.' });
            }
            else {
                var zip = new AdmZip();
                var zipName = randomstring.generate(5) + '.zip';
                zip.addLocalFolder(wd);
                zip.writeZip(path.join(__dirname, '../public/' + zipName));
                res.render('index', { message: message, success: false, attach: zipName });
            }
        });
    }

    function runTests(exec) {
        exec.stdin.setEncoding = 'utf-8';

        var output = '';
        var error = '';
        exec.stdout.on('data', function(data) {
            output += data;
        });
        exec.stderr.on('data', function(data) {
            error += data;
        });
        exec.stdout.on('end', function(err) {
            fs.writeFile(path.join(wd, 'stdout.log'), output, function(err) {
                if (err) console.log(err);
            });
        });
        exec.stderr.on('end', function(err) {
            fs.writeFile(path.join(wd, 'stderr.log'), error, function(err) {
                if (err) console.log(err);
            });
        });

        exec.on('close', function(code) {
            console.log('submission exited with code ' + code.toString());
            if (code != 0) {
                finishedWithError(true);
            }
            if (output == testcases[parseInt(req.body.problem)].output) {
                finishedWithSuccess(true);
            }
            else finishedWithSuccess(false);
        });

        exec.stdin.write(testcases[parseInt(req.body.problem)].input);
    }

    function proceed() {
        fs.writeFile(path.join(wd, sourcename), req.body.code, function(err) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
                res.render('error', { message: 'Error writing to disk.', error: { status: 500 } });
                return;
            }

            if (req.body.lang == 'cpp' || req.body.lang == 'c') {
                var gcc = spawn((req.body.lang == 'cpp' ? 'g++' : 'gcc'), [path.join(wd, sourcename), '-o', path.join(wd, req.body.problem)]);

                var stdout = '';
                var stderr = '';
                gcc.stdout.on('data', function(data) {
                    stdout += data;
                });
                gcc.stderr.on('data', function(data) {
                    stderr += data;
                });
                gcc.stdout.on('end', function() {
                    fs.writeFile(path.join(wd, 'stdout-gcc.log'), stdout, function(err) {
                        if (err) console.log(err);
                    });
                });
                gcc.stderr.on('end', function() {
                    fs.writeFile(path.join(wd, 'stderr-gcc.log'), stderr, function(err) {
                        if (err) console.log(err);
                    });
                });

                gcc.on('close', function(code) {
                    if (code != 0) {
                        finishedWithError(false);
                        return;
                    }
                    var exec = spawn(path.join(wd, req.body.problem));
                    runTests(exec);
                });
            }
            if (req.body.lang == 'py') {
                var exec = spawn('python', [path.join(wd, sourcename)]);
                runTests(exec);
            }
            if (req.body.lang == 'js') {
                var exec = spawn('node', [path.join(wd, sourcename)]);
                runTests(exec);
            }
        });
    }

    fs.mkdir(path.join(__dirname, '../sandbox'), function(err) {
        fs.mkdir(path.join(__dirname, '../sandbox/' + req.body.team), function(err) {
            fs.mkdir(path.join(__dirname, '../sandbox/' + req.body.team + '/' + req.body.problem), function(err) {
                proceed();
            })
        })
    });
});
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to CodeReview! I don't have a lot of time to review at the moment, but the fact you've created a system which allows remote code execution over a network and haven't included security worries me. Even if they are your friends, friends can sometimes do stupid stuff (like, for example, `fs.rmdir('C:\Windows\system32')`)

Comment: @ARedHerring Appropriate username. Jk. :P The thing is, I know about the level of trust we work with. And we have absolutely nothing else on the machine, so I'm willing to forego security, just for once.